# How to initialize Google protocol buffers Timestamp in Java?

Tags: java, timestamp, protocol-buffers

Google protocol buffers (3.0.0-beta2) offers the [well-known type Timestamp](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#timestamp).

The documentation describes the **initialization in Java** using *System.currentTimeMillis()* as following:

```
long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.newBuilder().setSeconds(millis / 1000)
    .setNanos((int) ((millis % 1000) * 1000000)).build();
```

Is there an **alternative way** in the recent **Java 8**?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Starting with **Java 8**, there is the new **Date/Time-API** which makes this more appealing to the reader using **[java.time.Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html)**

```
Instant time = Instant.now();
Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.newBuilder().setSeconds(time.getEpochSecond())
    .setNanos(time.getNano()).build();
```

The result should be the same concerning precision.

Answer (score 22):

These days, you can use:

```
import static com.google.protobuf.util.Timestamps.fromMillis;
import static java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis;
import com.google.protobuf.Timestamp;

...

Timestamp timestamp = fromMillis(currentTimeMillis());
```

See documentation at:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()
- https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/util/Timestamps#fromMillis-long-